# and() and any() with custom condition

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if there are any built-in tools in Python that work the same way [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [all()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) are implemented, but instead of checking if each element is truthy or falsy, you can pass your own boolean-evaluating function or lambda, sort of like you can do with the `map()` function.

So what I'm asking is if there are any built-in functions where you could do something like:

```
from random import randint
lst = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(1000000)]
has_even = any(lambda x: not x % 2, lst)
```

or

```
has_even = any(has_even_fn, lst)
```

where `has_even_fn` would be a function that checked if an integer is even.

You can still use `any()` to check if `lst` has evens:

```
has_even = any([not x % 2 for x in lst])
```

But of course this is strictly `O(n)` because the entire boolean list has to be built first, while the function I am asking for would only be `O(n)` in the worst case, and potentially `O(1)` in the best case.

Comment: Just remove the `[]` in `all` or `any` so the list comprehension will be turned to a generator expression. This includes some overhead but it doesn't eagerly transform the complete list.

Comment: "But of course this is strictly O(n) because the entire boolean list has to be built first" That's because you chose to use a list comprehension here. You can just use a generator expression instead: `any(not x % 2 for x in lst)`

Comment: You can also just use `map`.  `any(map(lambda x: not x%2, lst))`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Only in Python 3. With py2 one needs to use `itertools.imap`.

Comment: I will accept any of the generation expression comments as answers, they're exactly what I was looking for. A shame I neglected generator expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you can just remove the `[ ]` to get a *lazy-evaluating* generator expression instead of an *eager* list comprehension:

```
contains_one_or_more_even = any(x % 2 == 0 for x in lst)
```

or

```
contains_only_even = all(x % 2 == 0 for x in lst)
```